# How do I use a ChannelBufferOutputStream to check compression size

Tags: java, netty, apache-commons, java-io, apache-commons-io

In a java program I am compressing an InputStream like this:

```
ChannelBufferOutputStream outputStream = new ChannelBufferOutputStream(ChannelBuffers.dynamicBuffer(BUFFER_SIZE));
GZIPOutputStream compressedOutputStream = new GZIPOutputStream(outputStream);
try {
   IOUtils.copy(inputStream, compressedOutputStream);
} finally {
   // this should print the byte size after compression
   System.out.println(outputStream.writtenBytes());         
}
```

I am testing this code with a json file that is ~31.000 byte uncompressed and ~7.000 byte compressed on disk. Sending a InputStream that is wrapping the uncompressed json file to the code above, outputStream.writtenBytes() returns 10 which would indicate that it compressed down to only 10 byte. That seems wrong, so I wonder where the problem is. ChannelBufferOutputStream javadoc says: Returns the number of written bytes by this stream so far. So it should be working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Try calling `GZIPOutputStream.finish()` or `flush()` methods before counting bytes
2. If that does not work, you can create a proxy stream, whose mission - to count the number of bytes that have passed through it

Comment: 1) I think this was the problem, that I didn't close the output stream. Thanks! 2) I had the same idea, and there is CountingOutputStream in commons-io, however you will always get the uncompressed size since this is the number of bytes that the output stream will see.